# CORS failure with OAuth authentication in Spring server

Tags: angularjs, oauth, spring-boot, cors, jhipster

I have a CORS problem when I try to authenticate to my spring server calling the "oauth/token" endpoint.
The server answers with a 401 response

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/oauth/token.
 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
 Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access. 
 The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

This is how i call the server:

```
 login: function(credentials) {
        var data = "username=" +  encodeURIComponent(credentials.username) + "&password="
            + encodeURIComponent(credentials.password) + "&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&" +
            "client_secret=mySecretOAuthSecret&client_id=awhyapp";
        return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/oauth/token', data, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Authorization": "Basic " + Base64.encode("awhyapp" + ':' + "mySecretOAuthSecret")
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            var expiredAt = new Date();
            expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
            response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
            localStorageService.set('token', response);
            return response;
        });
```

OauthConfigurations:

```
 @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("...").permitAll()
    }
}
```

i followed the answer in this question ([Add headers to oauth/token response (spring-security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154167/add-headers-to-oauth-token-response-spring-security)) but my problem is that no matter how i configure my Filter class, those functions are never called even if i set the highest priority with @Order annotation.

Comment: I'm stuck with the exact same issue... Have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Un-comment **cors** in **application.yml**

```
cors: #By default CORS are not enabled. Uncomment to enable.
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers:
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
```

this worked for me when I was having the same error

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is redundant on the request. That is a response header.

In the linked answer, change the part to:

    `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type");`

This change lists allowed header values in the request you will send to the server.

I am unsure for your spring security configuration, but you should basically allow `OPTIONS` request on that endpoint to work without authentication.

Good luck.

Comment: I know that header is useless in the request but i was trying the impossible to make it work... 
My problem with what you suggest is that my custom Filter class, which implements the javax.servlet.Filter, is never called when i make a call to the oauth/token endpoint, even if i give to is the maximum priority with the @Order annotation.

Comment: It is due to your spring security configuration: it apparently requires authentication for every call, where it should allow `OPTIONS` request.