# Tomcat CORS filter and Spring Security

Tags: jquery, spring-security, cross-domain, tomcat7, cors

I am using Tomcat 7. I've set up native CORS filtering as suggested in the official Tomcat documentation.

I've tested everything I could, but it isn't working. Given that I am using a vendor application that I know is using Spring Security filters, I'm wondering if there is a known bug here.

Here is what I'm talking about:

```
<!-- Spring Security START -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- Spring Security END -->
```

I have added the following configurations to Web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I know it is minimal, but it should work.

I've also previously tried a longer version:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It didn't work either.

Does anyone have experience with setting up CORS filters with Spring Security?

Comment: Could you be more specific about "it's not working" ?

Comment: whats your exact tomcat version?

Comment: Did you try putting the cors filter before the spring filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vendor application must be enabled to respond on incoming preflight option requests with the appropriate CORS header. It is not a bug, it is just a configuration and / or some lines of code that are missing to enabled CORS for Spring. Enabling CORS is not a big deal for your vendor but it might become a big deal for you, especially if you don't have a copy of your applications java project in eclipse.

If you are lucky your vendor application already runs on Spring Framework 4.2 RC2 you can do the configuration in XML by yourself, see https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework. 
Simply try adding the `<mvc:cors>` block to your applications web.xml and configure the values according to your needs. I haven't tested it on my own, but it should do the trick.

But I fear you might not be that lucky...

Then things become a little tricky if you don't want to ask your vendor to updated the application / your WAR file. 
In that case, have a look on this post: [Can't set Authentication Header with Angular and Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936170/cant-set-authentication-header-with-angular-and-spring-security). The answer in the post describes the configuration that needs to be done in your application's `web.xml` *(create a new CORS filter and bind it to a class that you've to create)* and how the additional java filter class *(in the example the class is named `SimpleCorsFilter` in package `com.abcinsights.controller`)* has to look like to make it work. To add the new java class to your application, you have to unpackage your WAR, create and add the new java filter class (don't forget the package declaration inside your new java class) and repackage it. This is the most complicated part, because if you've made a mistake in your class or during repackaging, you'll probably see the error first time after re-deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar configuration and the key problem was that the `Authorization` header is not allowed in Tomcat's defaults for the `cors.allowed.headers` initialisation parameters. So I had just to add it like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Authorization,Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        <!--         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong. but every configuration file i've ever seen had the param names different than yours, perhaps thats the issue, what i've always seen and done was:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.maxAge</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add the CORS filter before Spring Security Filter in web.xml

CORS OPTIONS HTTP request doesn't need to be processed by Spring Security

Comment: well, Mourad is right. On a high level this is what has to be done.