# Polymer.js iron-ajax headers basic authorization not working

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm doing a cross origin request to fetch a json response from the url which has a Basic authentication. So on tap of the button, am setting the headers for basic authentication. When I print out the values before the request has been sent I see them. But when i check the chrome dev tool for request I don't see the headers been set. Also the request turns to be an "Options" request from "GET" request and the response comes as 401 unauthorized. Is there anything am missing?

```
 <paper-input type="search" value="{{imageUrl}}" placeholder="Enter Image URL"></paper-input> 
  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button on-tap="getData" autofocus>Search</paper-button>
  </div>
  <iron-ajax
  id="xhr"
  url="https://api.com/v1"
  params='{"url":"some query value"}'
  handle-as="json"
  method="GET"
  last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>

  getData: function(){
    this.$.xhr.headers['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
    this.$.xhr.headers['Authorization'] = this.makeHeaders(this.user, this.password);
    this.$.xhr.generateRequest();
  }
```

Comment: This lends me to believe that the browser is sending a preflight request with the options method to "https://api.com/vi" and you need to handle that option method by sending back http status 200 and then you call should be handled normally.

Comment: Check these urls:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632200/standalone-spring-oauth2-jwt-authorization-server-cors/30638914#30638914                                                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685678/cors-how-do-preflight-an-httprequest

Comment: @getbuckts Its actually an third party api service i'm hitting and it works when i'm doing it from postman. Also I tried with safari and firefox with same failure message. Not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: can you show what "this.makeHeaders()" code does?

Comment: makeHeaders: function(user, password){
        return "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + password);
      },

Answer (score 1):

By default `iron-ajax` does not send the [credentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) by default for cross-site requests

You can change this by setting the `withCredentials` property on the `iron-ajax`:

```
<iron-ajax
  id="xhr"
  url="https://api.com/v1"
  params='{"url":"some query value"}'
  handle-as="json"
  with-credentials="true"
  method="GET"
  last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
```

or

```
this.$.xhr.withCredentials = true;
```