# Angular 4.1 Basic authentication with springboot webservices

Tags: java, angular, web-services, spring-boot, angular-http

I'm trying to call Java springboot webservice with my Angular 4.1 application but there is a HTTP 401 error.

My springboot webservice works fine with Firefox or rest client but not with angular. I think it's angular typescript problem.

This is the Java EE error :

`Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied`

This is my angular code :

```
var headers = new Headers({authorization : "Basic " + btoa("j:j")});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let url: string = 'http://localhost:8080/wstest';
return this._http.get(url, options)
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.subscribe(datas => {
  console.log(datas);
});
```

When I use wireshark with browser webservice call, see basic autorization header :

```
Authorization: Basic ajpq\r\n
Credentials: j:j
```

But, with angular call, there is no credentials :

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
```

How can I call my springboot webservice with Angular 4.1 in order to add Basic authorisation credentials?

Comment: instead of  local host you can use your ip address

Comment: try it and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have the same problem. Credentials are not send and there is 401 HTTP error.

Comment: Do you cross the domain? if true you need enable CORS support on server.  Recommend using DevTools for Chrome inspect request content.

Comment: This is not cross domain error because server receive request and there is @CrossOrigin(allowCredentials="true") in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have find my response.

[Standalone Spring OAuth2 JWT Authorization Server + CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632200/standalone-spring-oauth2-jwt-authorization-server-cors?lq=1)

Springboot server must implements specific filter in order to allow angular "OPTION" webservice request.