# Setting order of CORS filter in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security-oauth2

I have developed RESTful application with Spring (I am not using Spring boot) and Spring security OAuth2 for endpoints security.
To allow CORS request in web browsers, I have added a CORS filter in my `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` in `onStartup` method for my oauth endpoint like this:

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addFilter("simpleCorsFilter",new CORSFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,false,"/oauth/token");
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
```

and for my other endpoints in `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

}
```

The source of my CORSFilter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632200/standalone-spring-oauth2-jwt-authorization-server-cors/30638914#30638914).

These solutions are working, as least not as completely as I expect. The filters are sometimes working in deployments on Tomcat and sometimes not.
I believe its because of the order of filters on Tomcat.

I have read many similar questions on SO and most of them are suggesting solutions for Spring boot which I'm not using.  I have also tried using Tomcat's corsfilter as well, but that doesn't work for me either.

Sometimes I have to restart my Tomcat more than 10 times to get everything work as expected.

Comment: *The filters are sometimes working in deployments on Tomcat and sometimes not* -- which problem do you face now?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna It's the same problem. I think the execution order of filter are shuffled. I need a way to make it the first filter triggered for requests.

Comment: You are using `spring-security` in your project, right?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have also enabled cors in spring security config

Comment: It might be a help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26147788/4423636

Comment: That's for Spring Boot. How could I do the same in a non-boot project?

Comment: @NimaAJ: Your first configuration in `onStartup` should not be needed unless Spring Security is not applied to all requests. Your second configuration works only for requests handled by Spring MVC (dispatcher servlet). For most cases it should be enough to configure CORS in your Spring Security configuration.

Comment: @NimaAJ: For authorization server security configuration you need the solution from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/330 (it should also work without Spring Boot).

Comment: @dur You are right! I solved my issue with disabling intercepting OPTIONS requests in Spring security configuration. The solution in your link will work as well and seems like a better solution. You could post it as an answer. Thanks