# CORS issue: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors, jhipster

I'm developing a spring boot application with jhipster V4.5.6. But unable to configure CORS.

Here is my application-dev.yml file:

```
 # CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile, so BrowserSync can access the API
cors:
    allowed-origins: "http://localhost:9000"
    allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers:
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

The WebConfigurer.java is as below:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = jHipsterProperties.getCors();
    if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
        log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
    }
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

And SecurityConfiguration.java file is as follows:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
        .antMatchers("/test/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .and()
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        ... //Some project specific configuration
}
```

Now, I'm able to work with GET request. But when I use POST as below:

```
private demoCors(restUrl: string, input: any): Observable<Result> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(restUrl, JSON.stringify(input), options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/dth 403 (Forbidden)
```

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/api/dth. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

Comment: You need to set a CORS Filter to allow your localhost to connect, please check this. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516755/spring-boot-rest-service-options-401-on-oauth-token/37517389#37517389)

Comment: It's already been set.
`@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = jHipsterProperties.getCors();
    if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
        log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
    }
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}`

Comment: You do not have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers

Comment: @jorrin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers are there in the response. I'm getting the response for OPTION request as follows: 
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type, x-xsrf-token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Max-Age:1800
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 07 Jul 2017 08:13:57 GMT
Vary:Origin`

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see where the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is

Comment: @jorrin, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000 Access-Control-Max-Age:1800`

Comment: @jorrin, I'm new to cors. I may have miss something

Comment: I have fixed the problem.. Thanks everyone for your suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this.

```
# CORS is only enabled by default with the "dev" profile, so BrowserSync can access the API
cors:
    allowed-origins: "*"
    allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers:
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

Comment: Yeah, I teied this.. Actually, CSRF was the culprit here.. So, I disabled CSRF for now, and it's working fine.