# JWT token missing using http get method in angular 4

Tags: angular, jwt, httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I am using HTTPClient Module of Angular 4 for retrieving data from a database.
The corresponding service has the following method,

```
getPosts() {
        const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
        httpHeaders.set('Authorization for JWT', 'Token');
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:9090/api/user' + '?user_id=' + this.user.id.toString(),
    {headers: httpHeaders,
    responseType: 'json'});
    }
```

I am calling this method from a component as follows,

```
this.Servie.getPosts().subscribe(pos => {
     console.log(pos);
   });
```

But I am getting an error as follows in server side,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: JWT Token is missing

error at the client side,

> Failed to load http://localhost:9090/api/user?user_id=1: Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500.

Please correct me where I am going wrong?

I Have made changes according to discussion below, but still problem is there as follows,
I think I have messed it up right now, I made the following changes as follows,    
      This is the code written in service,

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    .set('RequestAuthorization', 'Bearer ' + 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI5ODg0NjUxMjMzIiwidXNlcklkIjoiNSJ9.gwiZcx5I8rInXJGANvS9twupXjdjrzFdZNZ0K85u-KA8LXXDgDf27mUzUoiEyxRMg');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:9090/user' + '?user_id=' + this.user.id.toString(),
{headers: httpHeaders});
```

And i am calling the above service as follows,

```
    this.userServie.getPosts().map((res: Response) =>
   console.log(res.text()));
```

But the service is not hitting, i am not seeing the GET method in network tab of browser development tools. Where i am wrong ? Please correct me.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't the header be ('Authorization' , 'Bearer ' + jwt_token_here)

Comment: Bearer?, can you please tell me what is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850821/5283119 Here is a link which explains bearer and refresh tokens pretty well. Yeah you can set the content type application/json but it doesn't really matter to use a JWT token. The JWT token is the type of authorization to tell your app you are who you say you are.

Answer (score 1):

Headers have defined values.

```
httpHeaders.set('Authorization for JWT', 'Token');
```

Should be

```
httpHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```

If you provide random tokens to your server, of course it will tell you that the token is missing. In your case, you're sending this

```
Authorization for JWT --> Token
```

Comment: I have given the correct authorization token, the same has worked in postman software, here i have not given due to security purpose.

Comment: You should not do that. See how it is misleading. And apparently you didn't use `Bearer` in your token, so maybe you should try what I answered.

Comment: (And there is no security breach if you just give us your code, don't worry)

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me, what is `Bearer`? I am kinda new to this. Please help me to get the point. Thank You.

Comment: Bearer means `the one that bears` in english, and `to bear = to carry`. See it as something that bears your token. This is an authentication scheme. You can find **[more information here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)**

Comment: I have corrected my mistake as follows, `httpHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + 'AuthToken eyJh`)` But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Because it is `('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'eyJh')`. Be sure to put a space between bearer and your token too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167164/discussion-between-anil-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 0):

Once you figure out the real headers to send I think you'll have 2 problems:

**Issue #1**

`HttpHeaders` class is immutable

So you need to have something like this

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.set('Authorization', 'Bearer [yourTokenHere]')
```

instead  of declaring `httpHeaders` and calling set without chaining the call

```
const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
//The line below has no effect on the httpHeaders instance
httpHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Bearer [yourTokenHere]');
```

**Issue #2**

Also, did you make sure that CORS was configured properly on your java server?

You are getting an error about missing token for the `preflight` request (i.e. the one with the Options method). AFAIK, browsers do not send custom headers like `Authorization` for preflight requests. So, the server should not check the token for the OPTIONS request (otherwise, you'll always end up getting 401 as tokens won't be sent)

Comment: Hi David, I'm trying configure CORS, but not getting it properly , how can I do it plz?

Comment: It depends on your server, obviously java, which I don't know. I'm sure other SO users had that problem

Comment: With reference to the [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) ,  i have configured CORS in the server as follows,   
 `@RestController  
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9090")  
public class UserController {  
 
 @Autowired  
 private UserService userService;  
 
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =  
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<List<UserDomain>>  
 getAvailable(@RequestParam("user") String user){
 }  
}`

Comment: Does it work? There might be some more to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516755/spring-boot-rest-service-options-401-on-oauth-token and https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework  If you read the comments on the second link, you might have to do more work if using sprint 4.1 or older. But once again, I don't know java