# Zuul CORS filter doesn't work

Tags: java, cors, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

So, basically, the front-end uses reactJS, the back-end Spring Boot (microservices, with zuul acting as the gateway), and of course they can't do anything without CORS stuff.
We used this piece of code

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

and it worked, but it doesn't work anymore. I'm using Postman to check the headers that are sent back, and these are just not there.
What should I do? I could use a simple CORS filter in every microservice, but it would be way easier to let Zuul handle it all. Since all the requests are going to go through it anyway.
Any suggestions? Please, I'm extremely desperate.

Comment: Add code and problem you faced. [How to ask questions]https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

public SimpleCORSFilter() {
    logger.info("SimpleCORSFilter init");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD, PATCH, PUT");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}
```

Comment: Yes! This one worked! I've tried something similar, but I guess it must've been just different enough not to work.. 
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! A note, if using spring boot + oauth2, one might need this annotation on the class: @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE), ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485985/2893542