# Java Spring app can't run after deploy on Tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I just deployed (first time ever) my Java app based on Spring. On localhost everything worked fine, but after deploy I can't send any request. Applications just not running on the server.

Logs:

```
Oct  5 00:23:17 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:23:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Oct  5 00:23:17 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/TRADESYSTEM.war
Oct  5 00:23:17 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:23:17 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
Oct  5 00:23:17 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TRADESYSTEM/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct  5 00:23:17 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:23:17 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
Oct  5 00:23:17 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TRADESYSTEM/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.30.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TRADESYSTEM]]
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:560)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1779)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1506)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:285)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:205)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/GenericFilter
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3205)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1861)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:106)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:137)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:49)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5632)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: ... 43 more
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.GenericFilter
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: ... 55 more
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/TRADESYSTEM.war
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TRADESYSTEM]]
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:560)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1779)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor129.invoke(Unknown Source)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1506)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:285)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:205)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:23:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Oct  5 00:23:20 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/TRADESYSTEM.war has finished in 2,748 ms
Oct  5 00:25:54 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
Oct  5 00:25:54 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TRADESYSTEM/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct  5 00:25:54 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:25:54 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
Oct  5 00:25:54 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: validateJarFile(/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TRADESYSTEM/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.30.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Oct  5 00:25:56 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 12:25:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
Oct  5 00:25:56 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

Any sugestions what's wrong? I'll be more than grateful for any help.

EDIT:

If it helps - I've downloaded sample web project which I just deployed on server and it works well. That project has the above dependency, but difference is in logs after deploy. After deploy that sample app, in logs are typical spring logs:

```
Oct  5 01:23:36 vps-588e7d9b server: .   ____          _            __ _ _
Oct  5 01:23:36 vps-588e7d9b server: /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
Oct  5 01:23:36 vps-588e7d9b server: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
Oct  5 01:23:36 vps-588e7d9b server: \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
Oct  5 01:23:36 vps-588e7d9b server: '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
Oct  5 01:23:36 vps-588e7d9b server: =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
Oct  5 01:23:36 vps-588e7d9b server: :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)
```

but after deploy my app (with attached dependency) there's no logs like above. There's just info that application was deployed.

```
Oct  5 01:37:58 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 1:37:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Oct  5 01:37:58 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/app.war
Oct  5 01:38:00 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 1:38:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
Oct  5 01:38:00 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Oct  5 01:38:00 vps-588e7d9b server: Oct 05, 2020 1:38:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Oct  5 01:38:00 vps-588e7d9b server: INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/app.war has finished in 2,510 ms
```

Comment: you can try to use postman or curl to send request to your API and then check whether the cors headers are included in response or not
if they aren't, try a cors filter, you may find from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686029/zuul-cors-filter-doesnt-work

Comment: @SannTran when I'm trying to sent request via postman, I'm gettint 404 error. Now I'm really confused..

Comment: it means your api is not working. check the ip, port, and path is correct or not

Comment: @SannTran what's more, if I stop the java app at tomcat, the error is same. I haven't idea why it doesn't work because there's written that application is running

Comment: The 404 error is the real problem. The CORS error is just a side effect of that 404. In most systems, it’s normal and expected for 404 errors and other 4xx errors to lack the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. (But even if the 404 error did have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header it’d still be a 404 problem that needs to be fixed…)

Comment: @sideshowbarker now I'm sure that the issue is with back-end, because I can't even sent request via postman. But don't know why, application is running at tomcat

Comment: When you look at the server logs for that `http://ip-of-server/user/authenticate` server, what do the logs show? The server will log some message there before it sends the 404 response.

Comment: @sideshowbarker sorry for late answer, but I hadn't access do logs. I suppose that is main error :  4 23:46:18 xxx server: INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
Oct  4 23:46:18 vps-xxx server: Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Oct  4 23:46:18 vps-xxx server: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens

Comment: That looks like two errors: 1) *“Error parsing HTTP request header”* and *“ Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens”*. Those are both very unusual errors. I don’t really understand what could be causing those errors — but I’d suggest you use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64164940/edit to edit/update the question and cite those errors in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Issue was with version of Tomcat7 which was causing elManager error. I've solve that just by upgrading Tomcat to v9. Hopefully it'll helpful to  someone. Topic can be closed.