# Why requests are returned 404 status when using WebFilter corsFilter in webflux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, spring-webflux

I want to build a REST api in Spring Webflux using functional endpoints. For CORS I use a `WebFilter corsFilter` method which sets the required headers. I do see that the method is called (I see the log messages from it) and I see that the headers on the response are indeed the ones I set in my Webflux api. However, as soon as I started to use the `corsFilter` the requests return 404 status (earlier they would return JSON). I suspect that `corsFilter` doesn't pass over the request to the router functions. Why would that be?

Specifically I'm wondering if this line is enough to connect the cors config with the routes:

```
HttpHandler httpHandler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.webHandler(RouterFunctions.toWebHandler(route))
        .applicationContext(ctx).build();
```

This is my main class:

```
package com.mypackage;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions;
import org.springframework.web.server.adapter.WebHttpHandlerBuilder;
import reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.HttpHandler;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.POST;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.accept;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.contentType;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.method;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RequestPredicates.path;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions.nest;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions.route;
import static org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Server {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Server.class);
    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CorsConfiguration.class);
        Server server = new Server();
        server.startReactorServer(ctx);

        System.out.println("Press ENTER to exit.");
        System.in.read();
    }

    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routingFunction() {
        PersonRepository repository = new DummyPersonRepository();
        PersonHandler handler = new PersonHandler(repository);

        return nest(path("/person"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        route(GET("/{id}"), handler::getPerson)
                                .andRoute(method(HttpMethod.GET), handler::listPeople)
                ).andRoute(POST("/").and(contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::createPerson));
    }

    public void startReactorServer(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx) {
        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route = this.routingFunction().filter((request, next) -> {
            log.warn(request.path());

            if (request.path().contains("person")) {
                log.warn("calling next()");
                return next.handle(request);
            } else {
                return ServerResponse.status(UNAUTHORIZED).build();
            }
        });

        HttpHandler httpHandler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.webHandler(RouterFunctions.toWebHandler(route))
        .applicationContext(ctx).build();

        ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(httpHandler);
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(HOST, PORT);
        server.newHandler(adapter).block();
    }
}
```

and this is my CORS config class:

```
package com.mypackage;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsUtils;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class CorsConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CorsConfiguration.class);

    private static final String ALLOWED_HEADERS = "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN, mode";
    private static final String ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    private static final String ALLOWED_ORIGIN = "*";
    private static final String MAX_AGE = "3600";

    @Bean
    public WebFilter corsFilter() {
        log.warn("from CorsConfiguration!!!");
        return (ServerWebExchange ctx, WebFilterChain chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
            log.warn("after ServerHttpRequest");
            if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)) {
                log.warn("inside isCorsRequest");
                ServerHttpResponse response = ctx.getResponse();
                HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS);
                headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE);
                headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ALLOWED_HEADERS);
                if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
                    return Mono.empty();
                }
            }
            return chain.filter(ctx);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: the difference is that in the previous question I was looking for a way to implement CORS in the application. I found a way and update that question with an answer. Now Cors works but routing doesn't which is the point of this question.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you starting the server manually in the main function and setting up all routing by hand instead of using annotations and the built in spring boot features

Comment: @ThomasAndolf in webflux there're 2 programming models: Functional Programming Model and annotation based model. I wanted to use the function based model but I'm finding this to be more and more challenging.

Comment: you can probably remove almost everything in the main class. read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the functional approach when defining your endpoints Spring Boot's official documentation has a very simple example.

FooBarApplication.class this is our main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FooBarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FooBarApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

RoutingConfiguration.class (or whatever you wanna call it)

```
@Configuration
public class RoutingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> monoRouterFunction(UserHandler userHandler) {
        return route(GET("/{user}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), userHandler::getUser)
                .andRoute(GET("/{user}/customers").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), userHandler::getUserCustomers)
                .andRoute(DELETE("/{user}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), userHandler::deleteUser);
    }

}

@Component
public class UserHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getUser(ServerRequest request) {
        // ...
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getUserCustomers(ServerRequest request) {
        // ...
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> deleteUser(ServerRequest request) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

any class annotated with `@Configuration` will be run at startup and run all `@Bean` annotated methods. So this will run the `monoRouterFunction` and set up all our routes for us.

Example taken from the official spring boot documentation [Spring boot webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-webflux) scroll down a little bit.

EDIT:
and as a side note the `@EnableWebFlux` annotation means that you will disable the auto-configuration of webflux and set upp configuration manually. I do not recommend this if you are just starting out (i know the name is very misleading) you can read about the webflux auto-configuration here [Spring WebFlux Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-webflux-auto-configuration)

EDIT2:
WebFlux has a built in CorsFilter that you can use all you need is to configure it.

```
@Bean
CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
    CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://allowed-origin.com"));
    corsConfig.setMaxAge(8000L);
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("Baeldung-Allowed");

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
  new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

    return new CorsWebFilter(source);
}
```

Example taken from [Enabling CORS with a WebFilter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-cors)

Comment: but your example is missing the key part of my question: using CORS

Comment: we get the cors question here on stack overflow every 3 days. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-cors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46978794/enable-cors-in-spring-5-webflux
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689374/spring-5-webflux-functional-endpoints-no-access-control-origin-header-present-on

Comment: there is already a CORS filter in webflux, all you need is to configure it. Updated my answer.