# CORS doesn't work on Spring 4.3 with OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, cors, spring-security-oauth2

Here is what I'm getting in Chrome console when issuing request using Angular 1.5 app:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

When I remove OAuth2 configuration, error is gone.

This my CORS config:

```
class AppWebSpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ServletContextAware {

...

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("X-Requested-With", "X-Auth-Token", "Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }

...
}
```

And my OAuth2 config classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

}

@Configuration
class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final int ONE_HOUR = 3600;
    private static final int THIRTY_DAYS = 2592000;

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userSecurityService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                    .jdbc(dataSource)
                    .withClient(env.getProperty(CLIENT_ID_WEB))
                    .secret(env.getProperty(CLIENT_SECRET_WEB))
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ONE_HOUR)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(THIRTY_DAYS);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            final DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            return tokenServices;
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: I also tried with following filter implementation, but it doesn't work. I put a breakpoint in doFilter() method, but execution doesn't stop there, like my filter is not registered. However, when I added a default constructor to filter and put a breakpoint there - it stopped, which means that filter is registered.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCorsFilter implements Filter {

    public SimpleCorsFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

I also tried with this approach, but no luck once again: [Allow OPTIONS HTTP Method for oauth/token request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136532/allow-options-http-method-for-oauth-token-request)

I think that OAuth2 configuration is not allowing to request to even get through configured CORS filter.
Does someone know a solution to this problem?

EDIT2:
So, it turns out that there was a class:

```
public class AppSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    // nothing here, using defaults

}
```

Once i commented it, CORS configuration started working (probably due to filters passing) BUT now my OAuth2 configuration is not working at all! Every URL is exposed, without security. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Hiii I had same issue with spring 4.3 but resolved here is the answer :-

You need to override following method of AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter in your AuthorizationServerConfiguration class and add CORS filter there using addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter method of AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer as below:-

```
 @Override
 public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
       security.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(new CORSFilter());
 }
```

Your AuthorizationServerConfiguration class  will be :-

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userSecurityService);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                    .jdbc(dataSource)
                    .withClient(env.getProperty(CLIENT_ID_WEB))
                    .secret(env.getProperty(CLIENT_SECRET_WEB))
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ONE_HOUR)
                    .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(THIRTY_DAYS);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            final DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            return tokenServices;
        }

        // ***** Here I added CORS filter *****
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
              security.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(new CORSFilter());
        }  
}
```